# Remove program that isn't listed in apt-get

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I installed the program dolphin-emu on Ubuntu 16.04, but wanted to remove it and install a different version. I tried removing it but I can't see the package when searching for "dolphin" using "sudo apt-get --purge remove ..." or "apt list -installed" (the package should be called dolphin-emu). However I can still run the application from the user interface in Unity so it is clearly still installed.

I tried installing the version I want but it does not come up when I try to run it, only the older version that I want to get rid of! I tried to manually remove files and such but I think that made the whole thing worse and now I'm in some kind of mess that I can't resolve...

Comment: Does `sudo dpkg --remove dolphin-emu` help?

Comment: it says it is not installed. The problem is that it's not listed but it still exists